# How to index 4 fields in SQLITE when all four fields are using inequality operators

Tags: sqlite, indexing

In SQLITE I have a query

```
SELECT XMIN, YMIN, XMAX, YMAX, ID, Name FROM [table1] WHERE (XMIN <= -13037050.2764515 AND XMAX >= -13037062.8169015 AND YMIN <= 3988370.97273359 AND YMAX >= 3988358.43228364)
```

What index can I write which will improve performance the greatest?  I have already written an index which indexes the XMin, XMax, YMin, YMax fields like below.

```
CREATE INDEX "IX_wtrMainLnEs_XYFields" on wtrMainLnEs (XMIN ASC,XMAX ASC,YMIN ASC,YMAX ASC)
```

However when I run "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN" on the select statement, I see this as the result

SEARCH TABLE wtrLeaderLnEs USING COVERING INDEX IX_wtrLeaderLnEs_AllFields (XMIN

Which tells me that the index is only working on the XMin field.  Is there a way I can index all 4 fields in SQLITE?

Comment: No. See https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause_analysis for details.

Comment: It's possible the [R*Tree extension](https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) might be suitable for your data, though.